# Can you help me to understand the technical text translated from Chinese to English?

Tags: translation, meaning, usage

I am translating the user manual to Russian. It is in English but translated from Chinese and about Chinese video security system (chinese software and hardware).

Probably the native Chinese speakers would help me to understand the meaning of some parts of it that I believe are culture-dependent and should be understandable to people living inside Chinese culture and mentality - way of thinking, using and constructing linguistic  artifacts from Chinese-specific terms.

- First, the title of the manual: "The IOS Client Operations **that Ming**"
  What could chinese-speaking translator mean under "...that Ming"?
- Also, the phrase. "Mobile terminal main features include: **yuntai** control, ..."
  What does "yuntai" mean?

I do not have access to either original text or to described in manual products (video system or its software)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question is off-topic and too localized. [Chinese chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6586/) might be a better place for this kind of question.

My best guess for "The IOS Client Operations that Ming" is `IOS客户端操作说明` (IOS Client Operation Instructions) where Ming is the fragment from 说明 (instructions). Ming is obviously transliteration for a character and I can't think of any other word that fits the context and contains a Ming character.

"Mobile terminal main features include: yuntai control, ..." Yuntai is the Pinyin for `云台`, which means [tripod head](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tripod_head).